# Why do other racers show up in a GTA:5 solo session?

Tags: steam, grand-theft-auto-v

My SO has been playing GTA:5 on Steam in a solo session to learn how to play the game.
Occasionally, when entering a race point other names show up in the race queue.

We searched the web and there doesn't seem to be anything about this on there.

Is there any reason this might be happening?  Perhaps something we can check when it happens to be sure we're in solo mode?

Comment: Are you sure its not just AI names so you know you are racing against more than the clock?

Comment: @James Frankly, I am not sure; I know this is a question in a question but is there a way to check this?  I know we logged out and back in and they were gone from the same race, however, when we did not do this, they seemed to be in other races we started.  SO said the name appeared to be a handle and not an AI name, but we are not sure without a definitive way to check.

Comment: If you could provide us with a screen shot of it it might give us more information.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By "solo" session - I assume you mean online, but playing in invite-only and then starting races by yourself.

You probably have matchmaking enabled - other players are then able to join in your race through various methods, and do not have to be specifically invited.

To turn off matchmaking - open the menu and go to the Online tab, then locate Matchmaking in the online options and turn it off.

Comment: That setting was enabled.  I shall get back to you in a month to see if it occurs again.  Appreciated either way!!!